# Declarative Jenkins pipeline and Docker

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, ssh

I am just starting to look at Jenkins Declarative pipeline and running my builds in a docker container. I have a project that pulls in NPM packages via Git and thus need to have SSH keys set.

From what I have come across I can set build args such as `--build-arg ssh_pub_key="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"` and then in my Dockerfile

```
ARG ssh_pub_key
```

I have taken the following approach within my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      args '''--build-arg ssh_prv_key="$(cat /var/lib/jenkins-git/.ssh/id_rsa)"'''
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo $ssh_prv_key'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When running the build in Jenkins I get the below output when building the image (no mention of the `--build-arg`):

```
docker build -t 085eb412f6dd28c1a7843aa9f9ed84e7c4af3e1b -f Dockerfile .
```

and nothing for the variable.

Am I not setting them correctly? Is there another way to handle the copying of keys?

### Update

My Jenkinsfile now looks like below but will not run as get

```
Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

It seems I can't run any scripts outside of the pipeline declarative ?

```
def ssh_prv_key = sh script: 'cat /var/lib/jenkins-git/.ssh/id_rsa', returnStdout: true
def ssh_pub_key = sh script: 'cat /var/lib/jenkins-git/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', returnStdout: true

pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      args """--build-arg ssh_prv_key=\"${ssh_prv_key}\" --build-arg ssh_pub_key=\"${ssh_pub_key}\" """
    }
  }
    stages {
      stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'echo $ssh_prv_key'
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to also add `ENV ssh_pub_key=$ssh_pub_key` so that the SSH keys is made a part of the environment variables of the image. Right now you are passing the build arguments but not using them as such

Answer (score 1):

Here `$(cat /var/lib/jenkins-git/.ssh/id_rsa)` is a shell command.

AFAIK, bindings must have been declared outside of the pipeline line to use them when defining agents.

So, make the pipeline job parameterized.

- Add `ssh_prv_key` as a *Credentials Parameter*.
- Select `Secretfile`
- Set default value to the upload secretfile
- Repeat steps for `ssh_pub_key`

[image: Parameterized Pipeline]

Then use `ssh_prv_key` in `dockerfile` **`additionalBuildArgs`** directive.

```
 pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      additionalBuildArgs ""--build-arg ssh_prv_key=\"$ssh_prv_key\" --build-arg ssh_pub_key=\"$ssh_pub_key\""
    }
  }
    stages {
      stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh "echo $ssh_prv_key"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the assistance, where would i place this? outside of the pipeline block or within it ?

Comment: I usually place my variable definitions at the beginning outside of the pipeline block.

Comment: i've updated my question, would be interested to know how how you get that to run? thanks

Comment: Oops! `sh` directive has to be used in a pipeline context. Let me confirm this. I'll update my answer then

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, can this be done in a multibranch pipeline build though ? Can't see the option to paramatize

Comment: You're right about multibranch pipelines not supporting parameters. However, you can factor out the build steps to a downstream job where you can set parameters. https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/